# Disable auto scroll on Youtube

Tags: javascript

Switching between tabs while on a youtube channel page always auto-scrolls to the "content area".

How to prevent this auto-scrolling, I believe it can be done using browser extension but I couldn't find a way to interfere the process.

Disabling javascript is not an option because each tab content is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Well first you have to find out how they are scrolling the page. Or you can just wait for *n* seconds and move it back to the top.

Comment: I've actually tried this approach using `setInterval` but soon discovered it's unreliable because (1) you can't know exactly how long to set the interval time and (2) it will cause the page to scroll down then immediately back up which is far more annoying.